# How can I restore a WKWebView to the state it was before the app closed?

Tags: wkwebview

I run into a dead end. I just can't figure out a way for restoring a WKWebView after the user has closed the app. All the web pages he visited must be there when he re-opens it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

> All the web pages he visited must be there when he re-opens it

Impossible. The history of web pages visited - the `backForwardList`, and all its contents - is read-only. Nor is it saved and restored for you when you participate in view controller state saving and restoration.

In my opinion, this is a *major* flaw in WKWebView.

If you need this feature, revert to UIWebView, where it's all done for you like magic if you participate in view controller state saving and restoration.

Comment: And file a bug report with Apple!

Comment: @PeterLapisu No, my bug report is still just sitting there... If this is important to you, file your own bug report. Apple responds to quantity.

Answer (score 1):

you can store webpages in [NSDefaults standardUserDefaults] whenever the `WKWebView` has loaded.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation: (WKNavigation *)navigation{

}
```

Comment: @user3737190, it sounds to me that you want someone to type simple search requests into the browser for you. And what is "an NSData background" ?